# Mongo "E11000 duplicate key error" does not indicate which index caused the error when using WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection that contains documents like this

```
{_id : "Thing1", Version : 123 }
```

I have created a secondary index on the Version column so that value must be unique across all documents in the collection

```
{ v: 1, unique: true, key: { Version: -1 } }
```

When I use mmapv1, if I attempt to insert a duplicate document (that conflicts against that version key) I get an error like that says

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: local.Sample.$Version_-1 dup key: { : 1 }
```

But if I'm using WiredTiger, I don't get the index anymore:

```
E11000 duplicate key error dup key: { : 1 }
```

I would like to use the index to determine which column is failure so that I can retry differently depending on the failure.  Is there something in my configuration that's causing that value to be missing from the error?

Note: this is using Mongo 3.0

Comment: Seems to work fine with Mongo 3.2.0 and WiredTiger when I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug in Mongo 3.0.0.  The servers running the app weren't having this issue, only my local machine and I couldn't figure out what was different between the two for when I finally realized that the server was running Mongo 3.0.3.

Upgrading the local machine to 3.0.3 or newer resolved the issue.